# Lua ranme files before extension

Tags: lua

Im having issues on renaming a file with a tag before the extension
here is the filename sample i want to rename:

AudiA6.bin

My current code name tag is "---Tuned"

And returning it like this:

AudiA6.bin---Tuned

I want it to handle the file like this:

AudiA6---Tuned.bin

here is my smaple:

if (OpenProjectVersion (olsnaam, 1*versienummer)) then -- "1*" => cast to integer
if (projectExport (output_path..inputfile.."---Tuned", eFiletypeBinary)) then
OUTPUT:write ("done"); --File exported successfully
projectClose();
gevonden = "1";

if (OpenProjectVersion (olsnaam, 1*versienummer)) then -- "1*" => cast to integer
if (projectExport (output_path..inputfile.."---Tuned", eFiletypeBinary)) then
OUTPUT:write ("done"); --File exported successfully
projectClose();
gevonden = "1";

Comment: please put more effort into you post. typos even in the title, no code formatting...

Answer (score 0):

```
local fileName = "AudiA6.bin"
local tag = "---Test"
local newFileName = fileName:gsub("(.*)(%.%w+)", "%1".. tag .. "%2")
print(newFileName)
```

Please read the Lua manual